# MediaElement doesn't work silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, binding, mediaelement

Look I have like this code.

```
<MediaElement Source="Wildlife.wmv"/>
```

It didn't work.This file wildlife has placed in my project, I have changed in properties of Wildlife.wmv, Build Action on Resorces and it works!!!But it's useless for me becouse I'm using binding like this:

```
   <MediaElement Source={Binding ...}>
```

My question what I have to do if I take video file from openfiledialog and I can't change build action dynamic???It doesn't work, i can't find build action in some control or else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try looking here: [Change Source in MediaElement (SILVERLIGHT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248983/change-source-in-mediaelement-silverlight)

I think it may answer your question:

```
MyMediaElement.Stop();
Uri u = new Uri(openfiledialog.FileName, UriKind.Absolute);
MyMediaElement.Source=u;
MyMediaElement.Play();
```

Maybe you can also use Jason's answer there, and set the AutoPlay attribute to true.
Reagrds.